# jsf- validator with parameters from input

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

here a part of my .xhtml page:

```
<h:inputText id="kartNumIn"  value="#{controller.mitarbeiter.kartenNummer}">
                <f:attribute name="foo" value="controller.mitarbeiter.id" />
                <f:validator validatorId="kartVal" binding="#{kartVal}" disabled="#{!controller.noUpdate}"/>
            </h:inputText>
```

here my validate-method():

```
@Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        int id=(Integer) component.getAttributes().get("foo"); //always 0
        int temp = (Integer) value;

        if (!(value instanceof Integer)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Eingabefehler", "FEHLER:Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl ein!"));
        }

       System.out.print("Input"+value+"Aktuelle"+component.getAttributes().get("foo").toString());

        if (getAlleKartennummern().contains(temp) && temp!=id) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Kartennummerfehler", "FEHLER:Kartennumer bereits vergeben!"));
        }
    }
```

for my validator i need a second value. Here i need the `mitarbeiter.id`!  for `component.getAttributes().get("foo")` i get always null....

Comment: Please post real code which you really tested on a completely blank playground project with all settings to default (so that one could reprodice your exact problem by just copy'n'paste'n'running the code without doing any non-obvious changes/stubbing). The code posted so far seems to be careless oversimplified and does not match the problem symptoms. I'd expect some more "Deutsche Gründlichkeit" from a German developer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the OP is interested in the problem any more, but if someone else finds this question:

```
int id=(Integer) component.getAttributes().get("foo");
```

Will not work as you get a String. A little strange that you write that you always get null. You should get a:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

If this is the case, try:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt((String) component.getAttributes().get("foo"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the attribute you need to set the value of the expression

```
<f:attribute name="foo" value="controller.mitarbeiter.id" />
```

it should be

```
<f:attribute name="foo" value="#{controller.mitarbeiter.id}" />
```

Comment: I believe this is careless preparation of the question. OP mentioned that he got `null`, which would be impossible with a static string. The cause is more likely that the attribute value is dependent on a variable which is only known during view render time, such as the `var` of a `<h:dataTable>`.